# Polymer Data Binding within custom element

Tags: polymer

I've followed the examples from http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/binding-types.html#iterative-templates and I don't have working code.

I'm trying to make a form polymer element for a monster creation tool I'm making, because a friend of mine has good ideas for a monster battling game and I'd like to help him keep track of his ideas.

So I've made a custom element for a monster stat field. Since we're not 100% sure of what all the stats will finally be, I want to make this as modular as possible.

```
<link rel="import" href="../../../bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">

<!-- Calling noscript until I can better understand -->
<polymer-element name="monster-stat-field"
attributes = "stat value"
noscript
>

<template>
    <div id="name">
        {{stat}}
    </div>
    <div id="value">
        <paper-input
            type="number"
            error="Required, needs to be a number!"
            required
            label="{{stat}}"
            value="{{value}}"
            layout vertical>
        </paper-input>
    </div>
</template>

</polymer-element>
```

This should probably inherit paper-input, sure.

What I've done is nested it in another custom polymer element:

```
<link rel="import" href="../monster-stat-field/monster-stat-field.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../../bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../../bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">

<!-- Calling noscript until I can better understand -->
<polymer-element name="monster-form"
attributes = "name desc stats"
noscript
>
<template>
    <p>
        <paper-input
            label="Monster Name"
            value="{{name}}"
            required
            floatingLabel
            error="Required Field!">
        </paper-input>
    </p>
    <p>
        <paper-input
            label="Description"
            value="{{desc}}"
            floatingLabel>
        </paper-input>
    </p>
    <template repeat="{{s in stats}}">
            <p>
                <monster-stat-field stat="{{s.name}}" value="{{s.value}}">
                </monster-stat-field>
            </p>
    </template>

    <paper-button label="Save" raisedButton></paper-button>
</template>

</polymer-element>
```

And then on my main page I have:

```
<link rel="import" href="static/customComponents/monster/monster-form/monster-form.html">
...some other stuff...
    <monster-form
        name="Amalgam"
        desc="The Liquid Metal"
        stats="[
            {name: 'hp', value: 60},
            {name: 'cost', value: 60},
            {name: 'ene', value: 90},
            {name: 'str', value: 90},
            {name: 'wis', value: 75},
            {name: 'def', value: 95},
            {name: 'man', value: 90},
            {name: 'agi', value: 100}
            ]"
    ></monster-form> <br/>
    <p>Here is calling the monster stat field manually</p> <br/>
    <monster-stat-field stat="HP" value="60">
    </monster-stat-field>
```

So! What I have displaying is the name and the desc for the monster, but the stats are not there at all. Calling it manually does work, but I find this odd because I didn't import it explicitly.

Is this because I'm calling noscript? Or is it something else? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change two things to make it work:

Your JSON string for the `stats` attribute is not correct. You need double quotes arround the hash keys:

```
stats='[
            {"name": "hp", "value": 60},
            {"name": "cost", "value": 60},
            {"name": "ene", "value": 90},
            {"name": "str", "value": 90},
            {"name": "wis", "value": 75},
            {"name": "def", "value": 95},
            {"name": "man", "value": 90},
            {"name": "agi", "value": 100}
]'
```

And you need to hint the type of the `stats` attribute so that Polymer knows that it needs to convert it into an array. Remove the `noscript` attribute from the `monster-form` element and add a `created` handler function:

```
<script>
    Polymer('monster-form', {
        created: function() {
            this.stats = [];
        }
    });
</script>
```

Now Polymer will convert the `stats` attribute string into an array (of objects).

Comment: Couple of minor notes: (1) recent versions of Polymer will convert single-quotes to double-quotes for you before attempting JSON conversion (but it's still true that JSON requires you to quote all of the keys). (2) You can type-hint `stats` by simply placing it on your prototype (as `stats: []`) as long as you promise to never `push` to it (without making a fresh array first).

Comment: Good point, in this case I won't be, these should just be storing values.